# Recommendation on JavaScript Libraries available for doing resizing and draggable elements

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for recommendations on available JavaScript Libraries available for doing resizing and draggable elements on website. I have previously searched online and understand there have been a variety of them. I am new to web development and would like to seek some recommendations on those that you may have previously used before and would like to recommend. Thank you and look forward to hearing from your experience or knowledge!

I am looking for something similar to the one on google sites where it is able to drag and resize between 12 different columns etc. [image: Resizing example]

Answer (score 0):

In my case for this kind of problem I use the jQuery UI library.
You should be able to do something with the following documentation : https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement